# Counter example required

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> I am searching a counter example, if there exists one for this problem. Given $4$ densities $f_0$, $g_0$, $g_1$, $f_1$, with cumulative distributions $F_0(y)>G_0(y)>G_1(y)>F_1(y)$ and the relations $f_1/f_0$ increasing and $g_1/g_0$ increasing, is it possible that $f_1/g_1$ and/or $g_0/f_0$ is NOT increasing?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Start with four densities such that $F_0(y) > G_0(y) > G_1(y) > F_1(y)$ 
and $f_1/f_0$ and $g_1/g_0$ increasing.  Now if you modify these densities on
a small interval, the inequality on the cumulative distributions will still
be true.  Modify them in such a way that $f_1/f_0$ and $g_1/g_0$ stay the same, but  $f_0$ and $f_1$ become large near the beginning of the interval and small
near the end while  $g_0$ and $g_1$ become small near the beginning and large near the end.

Comment: I think something like the densities that I drew in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433552/comparing-the-relative-entropies-of-some-stochastically-ordered-distributions  right?